# How do I start Redis, a Ruby script, and Resque worker as one daemon

Tags: ruby, resque

I am building a Slack Bot that integrates with some internal tooling.

I see this solution: [Trying to start redis and resque scheduler within a rake task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5316054/trying-to-start-redis-and-resque-scheduler-within-a-rake-task)

But is there a cleaner way to do this?

Currently I am starting everything in yet another ruby script `start.rb` that is essentially this:

```
system('nohup redis-server &')
system('nohup bundle exec ruby slack_bot.rb &')
system("nohup bundle exec rake resque:workers QUEUE=* COUNT=#{$workers} &")
```

Generally this is fine, but for some reason the slack_bot hangs sometimes.  To restart, I have to kill that one process and restart it.  I would prefer to have an easy way to restart everything together just to be clean, essentially daemonizing the processes.  In a perfect world I could run this all as a system service and start/stop with `service bot start` or `/etc/init.d` or have a single process to start/kill.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you are looking for [foreman](https://github.com/ddollar/foreman) gem. With foreman you can declare various processes that are needed to run your application using a Procfile.

So, the solution can be:

1 gem install foreman

2 create Procfile in your project directory. Put into the file:

```
redis: redis-server  
slack_bot: bundle exec ruby slack_bot.rb  
workers: bundle exec rake resque:workers QUEUE=* COUNT=*
```

2.5 Now, you can use everything together through foreman:

```
$ foreman start
```

3 It is also possible to export foreman to system service.

```
$ sudo foreman export --app app_name --user your_user_name systemd /etc/systemd/system/
```

3.5 Launch the service

```
$ systemctl start app_name.target
```

Foreman detailed documentation available [here](https://ddollar.github.io/foreman/).

Comment: Exactly what I needed, works perfectly with `foreman start` and I can run it in a screen to make it persistent.  When I try to do the system service part, Redis does not start, the other parts do. I read somewhere that there may be an issue with the '-' in the Redis line.